# ftp cmd not found after install proftpd

Tags: ftp, proftpd

I have install ftp service with :

```
sudo apt-get install proftpd
```

I would try ftp connexion with `ftp` (I try with and without sudo) cmd, but :

> command not found

what wrong?

Comment: Which distribution?

Comment: im on debian 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

proftpd is only a FTP server and does not have to contain ftp client. You should install ftp client (sudo apt-get install ftp).

Comment: yes, that not precised on tutoriel I following -_-'